# How to identify rows where observations are identical in two different columns in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, mutate

I have two columns, let's call them start_id and end_id, each with character string observations. Their structure must remain as chr.

This is in a dataset with millions of rows.

I would like to create a new column that evaluates if start_id = end_id. If they are equal, I'd like it to evaluate TRUE, if not, FALSE.

I'd like the new column to be permanent, and not temporarily stored.

```
df_new <- df %>% 
       mutate('new_column' = if_else('start_id' == 'end_id', TRUE, 'start_id' != 'end_id', FALSE))

#This ran without error, but when I looked at df_new, the evaluations were not correct. In fact, all returned as TRUE, when some should have been FALSE.


#Help a newb! Thanks!
```

Comment: @TarJae why use ifelse?

Comment: The reason why you are getting incorrect values is because of using character values instead of column names. ie you are comparing `'start_id'` to `'end_id'` instead of comparing what the two columns contain. just do `df%>%mutate(new_column = start_id == end_id)` you do not need the quotes

Comment: Thank you! This worked after I took the single quotations off.

Comment: To onyambu's earlier point, generally `ifelse(blah, TRUE, FALSE)` is saying *"if `blah` is TRUE then TRUE, if `blah` is FALSE then FALSE"*, which is a long way to write `blah`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I first defined a data frame including two char columns, as you said, 'start_id' and 'end_id.' Then, I used mutate with a condition to create the new column.

```
# Create a data including two columns: start_id, end_id

start_id = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven")
end_id = c("one", "three", "two", "four", "seven", "six", "five")


df = data.frame(start_id, end_id)
df
```

```
# create a new column which is True if start_id equals end_id, otherwise it is False.
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
  mutate(status= if_else(start_id == end_id, TRUE, FALSE))
df
```

Comment: Most `dplyr` functions expected unquoted column names, using `.$` works in cases like this with ungrouped data, but will not work with grouped data. I'd suggest avoiding `.$`.

Comment: Also `'True'` and `'False`' strings are generally much less useful than `TRUE` and `FALSE` logical values. There's no reason to change that from OP's code.